Filtration of wedge of spheres
I'm taking an algebraic topology class and playing around definitions, and I can't answer the following question.
Let $K$ be a simplicial complex with the homotopy type of a wedge of spheres, $K \simeq \bigvee S^k$.
Is it possible to construct a filtration of $K$ with torsion in some degree $d \leq k$?
Thank you for the help!

What do you mean by "filtration of $K$ with torsion in some degree $d \leq k$?" Torsion in homology?

Yes, torsion in homology.

Let $C$ be the cone on $\mathbb{R}P^2$; then you should be able to find a filtration of that which yields torsion in homology. Since $C$ is contractible, $C \vee S^3 \vee S^3$ has the homotopy type of a wedge of spheres. ($C$ itself has the homotopy type of an empty wedge of spheres, too.)
